# php excel cell data validation to include cells from another sheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm using php excel to export data file, I have a column called 'group', the user should select the group from a list of groups, so I use cell data validation to make a list as following

```
$cell='A5'
$validation = '$A$2:$'A$10';  

     $objValidation = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getDataValidation();
    $objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
     $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
    $objValidation->setFormula1($validation);
    $sheet->getCell($cell)->setValue('group5');
```

in this case I have to set default value for each cell, so the validation gets the list from cells

I use a macro to make mutli-selection list, the default value makes problems with the macro

so I need to have the groups column in a separated sheet and use this sheet in the validation formula in the first sheet, so I can have something like

```
$validation= 'Sheet2$A$2:$'A$10';
```

Is this applicable?

Comment: Your quotes make this invalid PHP

Answer (score 1):

You may change the string delimiter you use. But I think Excel address work like that: `Sheet2$A$2:$A$10`

So you don't need this extra quote, that breaks your string in your php:

```
$cell='A5'
$validation = '$A$2:$A$10';  

$objValidation = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setFormula1($validation);
$sheet->getCell($cell)->setValue('group5');
```

hope it helps

Comment: Hi, how can you change the delimiter for the list? $objValidation->setDelimiter(';'); doesn't seems to work?